# Is there a limit on how many questions can be asked in a given time frame?

Tags: support, questions

I'm new to the site, and part of a group that is relatively new to Pathfinder. I've been asking a lot of questions (I think, anyway) and I can't help but wonder if I'm breaking a rule. I have more questions to ask, but I'm worried about getting banned or the like.

Answer (score 7):

Good question. In general we ask you to use common sense. Let these 5 questions get real answers and then move on. I would suggest that you don't have more than 3-4 active at any given time.

Comment: Could you define 'active,' please? Would that imply that I've chosen an answer, or that people have stopped giving answers?

Comment: @Zach: A good definition would probably be "on the first page if you sort by by active questions".

Comment: Active = on first page with an unaccepted answer. We recommend that you wait 24 hours or so before accepting, cause not everyone obsessively watches this stack.